# What Minecraft biomes are hot, temperate, and cold?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What *Minecraft* biomes are hot, temperate, and cold? I'm looking for a list with details, or a 2D chart/spreadsheet with multiple rows and a few columns with the relevant details: concise.

I've looked online for this and other biome-related information, and always found it missing whatever I was looking for, not being concise, or just having terrible results. In other words, I didn't find what I was looking for elsewhere.

Comment: If you're looking for something more quantitative, Sportskeeda has a complete list of biomes with the numerical temperature values used by the game's code next to each. To quote the article, "Minecraft biome temperatures range on a scale from -0.7 being the coldest to 2.0 being the warmest. Within that range, the biomes can be considered dry, temperate, cold, snowy, or aquatic based on the individual environments." *Unfortunately, the page is covered in obnoxious ads.* View at your own discretion: https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/ranking-coldest-warmest-minecraft-biomes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [fandom wiki page on frogs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Frog#Spawning) as a source:

Its pretty intuitive overall, but any biome with "frozen" or "snowy" in the name, along with the end (except for void which is temperate) and deep dark are considered cold. Jungle, desert, badlands, (luke)warm ocean, mangrove swamp and nether biomes are warm with the remainder being temperate